# Getting no State error with simplesamlphp library v 2.13

Tags: drupal, simplesamlphp

I have updated simplesamlphp library form v1 to v2
after which i am getting NO state error

I have checked store.type in config.php is sql

I was trying to see simplesamlconfiguations as a admin but got the below  error

> SimpleSAML\Error\NoState: NOSTATE Backtrace: 6 src/SimpleSAML/Auth/State.php:275 (SimpleSAML\Auth\State::loadState) 5 modules/core/src/Controller/Login.php:103 (SimpleSAML\Module\core\Controller\Login::loginuserpass)